# Difference between $('#id') and $("#'+"id"+'")

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out the difference between `$('#id1')` and `'@$("#' + "id1" + '")'`

```js
var DA_input1 = $('#id1');

var DA_input2 = '@$("#' + "id1" + '")';


$("#test1").click(function(){
   alert(DA_input1.val());
});
$("#test2").click(function(){
  alert(DA_input2.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input data-target="datable" id='id1' value="50">

<br>

<button id="test1">test1</button>
<button id="test2">test1</button>
```

with `$('#id1')` i'm getting the value correctly but with `'@$("#' + "id1" + '")'`  console returning error as `DA_input2.val is not a function`

please help

> Can we convert the string(DA_input2) as object? (like DA_input1)

PS:
People who are downvoting this, please mention the reason. I'm i violating any Stackoverflow rules or is this question answered anywhere? or you guys blindly following first downvote? please let me know

Comment: What do you expect `DA_input2` to be? Without any pre-processor, `DA_input2` is literally the string `'@$("#id1")'`. Strings don’t have a `val` method.

Comment: The first is a JQuery valuation, while the other is a simple string.

Comment: got it thanks but Can we convert that string as object/element?

Comment: `var elD = '#id1'; var input = $(eID);`

Comment: Thanks @Dementic it's working

Comment: '@$("#id1")' is nothing just string while $('#id') return DOM element so it return value

Comment: I don't know why people are down voting this question. am i violating any rules or is it already posted anywhere or duplicate question? seems like downvoted guys don't know the rules of stackoverflow i think

Comment: People forgot you need to begin somewhere.

Comment: @Dementic please add it as answer. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// JQuery evaluation of a selector
var DA_input1 = $('#id1');
// Simple string
var DA_input2 = '@$("#' + "id1" + '")';
```

if you would like to specify the id in a variable and make JQuery evaluate the string in the variable, you could do:

```
var selector = '#id1';
var $input  = $(selector);
```

Please note i named the variable `selector`, since it can be any css selector,
e.g:

```
var selector = '.classNameHere';
```

which would select all elements which have the class `classNameHere`